# dasBlog and using C# as category for tag cloud

Tags: c#

I am using dasBlog for my Blog and one of the categories I have is C#.  Now when I click on this tag, it takes me to /CategoryView.aspx?category=C thus removing the hash.  Does anyone know a quick way of either:

- fixing this and keeping C# as the tag OR
- locating the data store for the categories and changing to "CSharp"

Thanks in advance

Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no ways to fix dasBlog to use exactly "/CategoryView.aspx?category=C#" url because '#' is a [special character](http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/prop_loc_hash.asp) in links. You also can use the way stackoverflow is use (using "c%23" instead of "c#") but I think that you'll need to fix some code in dasBlog to achieve this.
Also you can rename this category using [category renamer](http://www.vasanth.in/software/renamer-dasblog-category-renamer/)

Comment: Thanks for that.  Unfortunately that guy is migrating links so the download does not work at present.  I will send an email though and ask for the prog, and thank you for the excellent answer!!! :-)